# How to programmatically connect to a service using C#?

Tags: c#, service, ssis

I am building an ETL process using SSIS to call data from a report API and load the data into a SQL database. I am running into issues with the initial steps where I call the service using a C# Script task. The documentation provided by the vendor shows how to connect to the service as an application using a connected service, which works successfully, However I can not use an XML configuration file in my SSIS project and need to programmatically connect from within the C# script task.

This is a little outside of the things I am familiar with and have not been successful in finding a solution to yet.

Per the client documents I first need to add a service reference to my project:

```
https://services.fakename.com/BulkReportExternalAPI/FakeNameReportService.svc
```

From there I can call the litany of functions the API provides so long as I pass valid credentials.

But this method relies on the `.config` file I am trying to eliminate.

The XML config reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration
   <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
   </startup>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFakeNameService">
               <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
            </binding>
         </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
         <endpoint address="https://services.fakename.com/BulkReportExternalAPI/FakeNameReportService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFakeNameReportService"
            contract="FakeNameReportService.IFakeNameReportService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFakeNameReportService" />
      </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Within the C# script, the basic connection test looks like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var client = new FakeNameReportServiceClient();
   var credentials = client.ClientCredentials;

   if (null == credentials)
      throw new ArgumentNullException();

   credentials.Username.Username = "fakeUserName";
   credentials.Username.Password = "fakePassword";

   var userAgent = new UserAgent()
      {
         CompanyName = "YourCompany",
         ApplicationName = "SampleClient",
         ApplicationVersion = "1.0.0.0"
      };

   MessageBox.Show(client.TestConnection(userAgent));
}
```

This is of course for an application with a button that I will not be using, but if I can make it work without the use of the `.config`, will get me where I need to be with the project.

And guidance anyone has on this would be greatly appreciated

I have tried using `WSDL.exe` to generate a C# class and this partially worked as it gave me all of the service functions, but does not allow me to define the client. It seems C# class the `WSDL.exe` created doesn't use the `System.ServiceModel` or create the `FakeNameReportServiceClient` that allows me to pass credentials.

I've also tried using the `svcutil.exe`, but that still generates a `.config` along with the C# class so I am not certain if will help yet.